# Multiprocessing logging in Google App Engine Flexible not working

Tags: python-3.x, google-app-engine, logging, google-app-engine-python, google-cloud-logging

So we have gone from using a single thread application to expanding to processes in google app engine flexible. Problem is that logging is not working when we run the GAE app, but it works if I log from my local machine. Getting the logger is using the following function:

```
def getLogger(self, name: str):
    if not self.instance.logging_setup:
        if self.execution_in_cloud():
            client = google.cloud.logging_v2.Client()
            client.get_default_handler()
            client.setup_logging(log_level=self.get_log_level())
            logging.StreamHandler().setFormatter(StackdriverFormatter())
        else:
            logging.basicConfig(format='%(asctime)s %(levelname)-8s [%(threadName)s] %(name)-15s %(message)s',
                                stream=sys.stdout,
                                level=self.get_log_level())
        self.instance.logging_setup = True
    return logging.getLogger(name)
```

So this works perfectly, all loggers fetch this function from this context class. If a new process is spawned, the logging will be setup for that handler. Logging from the processes works locally, but not when running in the GAE App. Is this a known issue, or is it another setup of the logger that is required?

Comment: How did you setup multithreading in GAE? Is this your only multithreading process?

Comment: In what way is logging "not working"? Do you get an error message? Is nothing logged at all? Are you seeing different log message from what you expect?

Comment: Sorry for late answer. Here is the code example that I tried: https://gitlab.com/recapital-public/python-logger-error-gae, When I run locally with the PRODUCTION = true environment, all logs ends up in the project on google. When I deploy the gae app there is no logs in the gae app or anywhere else from the process. @David

Comment: Running under GAE, the logs will be emitted with a different resource type and label than when it is running somewhere else. Have you checked the stackdriver console for the gae_app resource type (e.g. [here](https://console.cloud.google.com/logs/query;query=resource.type%3D"gae_app")

Comment: So I looked at all logs (meny -> stackdriver) and it is nowhere to be found, and that is vm and all that is available for our projects afaik.